# Postfix to Prefix Conversion using Prolog

Tags: prolog

Can anyone help me to write a program using stack concept in **PROLOG** to convert an arithmetic expression from postfix(reverse polish notation) to prefix form. The arithmetic expression may contain the 4 arithmetic operators **+ , - , / , *** and the unary functions : `sin, cos, tan, exp, log and sqrt.`

Comment: why do you need a stack ? Prolog is already a 'stacked' language.

Comment: What exactly is the input format? (And to answer your question: yes, I can)

Comment: The input format and expected output format is as follows             ?- post2pre([9,4,+,2,5,-,exp,/],X).
X = [/,+,9,4,exp,-,2,5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[append](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2)/2 it's a useful list combinator. It allows in fairly general way a *relation* of concatenation among an arbitrary number of lists. I'll show just the basic here, you'll need to complete your assignment adding some detail as unary functions, define isop/1

```
pos2pre(Pos, Pre) :-
    append([A, B, [O]], Pos), isop(O), A \= [], B \= [],
    pos2pre(A, APre),
    pos2pre(B, BPre),
    !, append([[O], APre, BPre], Pre).
pos2pre([P], [P]).
```

a little test:

```
?- pos2pre([1,5,*,2,+],X).
X = [+, *, 1, 5, 2].
```

I think you should try to write the same logic but using [append](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3)/3, that would help you to understand how the procedure works.