# converting a list that contain an equation

Tags: prolog, dcg

I have a question regarding Prolog. Actually I have a Prolog function that call a list of numbers and signs and I want to convert the list from post equation to pre equation. for example if I have the list and the result to store the resulted equation.

the function call will contain for example:

```
|?- convert([20,30,+,41,11,-,ex,/],E).

E=[/,+,20,30,ex,-,4,1]
```

Comment: please show some effort to solve it !

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really understand what you're trying to do. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: It's funny, I didn't remember I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15025946/874024) the very same question 1 year ago