# Postfix to prefix conversion in prolog with Unary Operators of sin cos tan etc

Tags: data-structures, prolog, stack, logic

I New to Prolog. I am trying to learn this. I was building a postfix to prefix conversion predicate. I searched a lot google and github etc. prolog recursive syntax is very confusing. By searching a lot I just [found this one link on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022133/postfix-to-prefix-conversion-using-prolog/15025946#15025946). I Exactly working on same problem but the solution specified is very confusing. The append/2 function implementation is not coming in my mind, and also what about the uniary operators? It is now more then 3 days I am continuously working on this problem and just got sucked. Any one please help me to implement this logic or any book reference or some link to get better understanding regarding the same problem. Thanks

I thought to solve it in this way

```
    post2pre([A,B,C|Rem],Pre) :- Pre=[C,A,B], isop(C).
```

But the problem is What to do with Rem? and what if I just have one or two items in the list
I thought to solve it like this

```
   post2pre([A|[]],Pre) :- Pre=[A].
   post2pre([A,B|[]) :- Pre=[A,B].
```

and for isOp() i defined them as

```
   isop(+). isop(-). isop(*). isop(/). isop(sin). isop(cos). isop(exp).
```

but I do not know what to do with uniary operators?

Comment: I had run the code specified in link I post. But the problem is my mind is still unable to think in prolog's way.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as I advised in that answer, pos2pre/2 it's just a sketch, to be completed by the student. But it's also a tricky solution, imho rather declarative. As such, it's easily extended to handle unary operators (I'll rename isop/1 as is_binary_op/1, to cleanup the code):

```
pos2pre(Pos, Pre) :-
    append([A, B, [O]], Pos), is_binary_op(O), A \= [], B \= [],
    pos2pre(A, APre),
    pos2pre(B, BPre),
    !, append([[O], APre, BPre], Pre).
pos2pre(Pos, Pre) :-
    append([A, [O]], Pos), is_unary_op(O), A \= [],
    pos2pre(A, APre),
    !, append([[O], APre], Pre).
pos2pre([P], [P]).

is_binary_op(O) :- memberchk(O,[+,*]).
is_unary_op(O) :- memberchk(O,[sin,tan]).
```

test

```
?- pos2pre([1,2,3,+,*,sin],Pre)   .
Pre = [sin, *, 1, +, 2, 3].
```

An alternative way I would try to follow would use a totally different scheme, building an *infix* expression parser (a DCG), and then let the postfix/prefix *visit* of the tree to transform between formats.

*edit* here is the append/2 predicate stolen from SWI-Prolog library(lists):

```
append(ListOfLists, List) :-
    must_be(list, ListOfLists),
    append_(ListOfLists, List).

append_([], []).
append_([L|Ls], As) :-
    append(L, Ws, As),
    append_(Ls, Ws).
```

The ! symbol is named *cut*, and it's not an operator, but a system predicate (more precisely, a control predicate). It always succeeds, and *prunes* alternatives that could be pending at execution point, thus committing to choices done so far. You should read some online [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=!/0) about this topic...

Comment: The gnu compiler do not support append/2 function i think. and all over the internet I look for Append function they do this with append/3 how the implementation of these two function is different? and can you please tell about the ! operator use here?

Comment: @AbdulRehman, SWI Prolog has `append/2` and `append/3`. `append/3` is in GNU prolog as well. If you look up the descriptions of those predicates on the SWI Prolog site, you'll see the difference. The short answer is that `append/2` assumes the first argument is a "list of lists" which it appends into a single list (the second argument). `append/3` operates at a single list level and the third argument represents the second argument appended to the end of the first argument. NOTE that with each of these predicates, you can give it any arguments and it will generate solutions for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate version. This one builds the prefix structure from the postfix list first as a nested list structure of 2- or 3-element lists (per unary or binary op) and then just flattens the nested list at the end:

```
post2pre(Post, Pre) :-
    post2pre(Post, [], Pre).

post2pre([E|T], PreNest, Pre) :-
    (   unary_op(E)
    ->  PreNest = [Term|PNT],
        post2pre(T, [[E,Term]|PNT], Pre)
    ;   binary_op(E)
    ->  PreNest = [Term2,Term1|PNT],
        post2pre(T, [[E,Term1,Term2]|AP], Pre)
    ;   post2pre(T, [E|PreNest], Pre)
    ).
post2pre([], PreNest, Pre) :-
    flatten(PreNest, Pre).

unary_op(X) :-
    memberchk(X, [sin, cos, tan]).

binary_op(X) :-
    memberchk(X, [+, -, /, *]).
```

In the above code, an "atomic term" is implicitly defined as anything that is not an operator.

Per the example:

```
| ?- post2pre([1,2,3,+,*,sin],Pre).

Pre = [sin,*,1,+,2,3]

yes
```

The "intermediate" nested form in this case, before the `flatten` occurs, would be:

```
[sin, [*, 1, [+, 2, 3]]]
```

A non-if-then-else version of the above code could be written as follows. I opted for the if-then-else construct above since it avoids redundantly checking the operator:

```
post2pre(Post, Pre) :-
    post2pre(Post, [], Pre).

post2pre([E|T], PreNest, Pre) :-
    atomic_term(E),
    post2pre(T, [E|PreNest], Pre).
post2pre([E|T], [Term|PNT], Pre) :-
    unary_op(E)
    post2pre(T, [[E,Term]|PNT], Pre).
post2pre([E|T], [Term2,Term1|PNT], Pre) :-
    binary_op(E)
    post2pre(T, [[E,Term1,Term2]|AP], Pre).
post2pre([], PreNest, Pre) :-
    flatten(PreNest, Pre).

atomic_term(X) :-  % This defines a term explicitly as anything but an operator
    \+ unary_op(X),
    \+ binary_op(X).

unary_op(X) :-
    memberchk(X, [sin, cos, tan]).

binary_op(X) :-
    memberchk(X, [+, -, /, *]).
```